# Recursive Makefile inter-dependency tracking

Tags: recursion, makefile, cmake

Let's say I have a directory structure like the following:

```
root->utils
root->lib
root->bar->lib1
root->bar->lib2
root->foo->lib3
```

`utils` is completely independent, however `lib1` and `lib2` depend on `utils`.  Furthermore, `lib3` depends on `lib1`.

A recursive make would look something like this:

```
all:
  $(MAKE) -C utils
  $(MAKE) -C bar/lib1
  $(MAKE) -C bar/lib2
  $(MAKE) -C foo/lib3
```

However, I have two requirements.  First, I need to support parallel builds.  Second, I would like to be able to build subdirectories independently.  The first requirement is seems impossible for Makefiles unless I create some sort of `JOBS=1` variable and then invoke each make with `-j$(JOBS)`, however this still isn't truely parallel since it won't do `lib1` and `lib2` at the same time after `utils`.  The second requirement means that the Makefiles for `lib1` and `lib2` also have to invoke `$(MAKE) -C $(TOP)/utils`.  I have read most of the paper dealing with making one global Makefile, but I don't like the lack of modularity.

Is there a way around these inefficiencies and redundancies?  Is there a standard way to deal with them?

Does CMake solve these problems under the hood, or does it just keep it all from view?  In other words, would invoking a parallel make that was generated by cmake potentially build `lib1` and `lib2` in parallel, or does it go through the same redundancies?

Finally, what happens if I invoke `$(MAKE) -C utils` from both `lib1` and `lib2` at the same time?  Will the requests lock themselves appropriately, or will they collide and make a mess of things?

Comment: What "lack of modularity" are you talking about? And it is *exactly* these issues that the recursive make considered harmful paper argues is the problem with recursive make and for which there are no good general solutions.

Comment: For the same reasons that it is generally bad practice to have one single enormous source file for the entire project, I believe it is bad to have one global Makefile.  For simple projects, it probably works just fine (as does recursive make).  For complex projects, each module may have specific compilation nuances which are best addressed within its own makefile scope.  For instance, people working on multiple modules with different compiler flags/settings/defines/etc all have to make their own flag variables lest they run into problems overwriting each other.

Comment: I was curious about cmake because it seems to fix the scoping problem, but I was curious about what other differences there might be (the additional level of makefile generation for example).

Comment: Nothing about not having recursive make requires you to have a single makefile. Just one make instance that builds it all. That can absolutely have rules spread over various makefiles (which can even with the right amount of effort be used stand-alone when necessary).

Comment: I don't know enough about cmake's generated makefiles to know what it does about this but at a guess all it does is embed all the combined knowledge into every makefile in every directory so that they are all complete copies of everything they need to know.